# Sharekit Application tried to push a nil view controller on target / empty actionsheet

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, cocoapods, sharekit

I've updated a project to use Sharekit 2.0 installed via cocoapods.

A test bed application using the mySHKConfigurator.h and mySHKConfigurator.m works perfectly.

But when I install Sharekit the same way in the actual project using the same mySHKConfigurator.h and mySHKConfigurator.m files I have two problems

The actionSheet has only the 'more...' option

When the 'more...' option is pressed the app freezes after loading a black modal view with

"Application tried to push a nil view controller on target"

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. I am facing the similar problem. Did you get it resolve?